# TXR collecting data from a table with ill-defined separator

Tags: text-processing, txr

I have data output that looks like the following:

```
Item Time    Type   Width     Area      Area    Name
   #   [min]            [m]      [m^2]        %
----|-------|------|-------|----------|--------|---------------------
   1   0.323  A B    0.0000    0.00000  0.00000 ABC                                              
   2   1.581  C      0.0000    0.00000  0.00000 DEF                                              
   3   2.898  D2     0.0000    0.00000  0.00000 GHI                                              
Totals :                       0.00000
```

The challenge with this data is that there is no obvious column separator other than the position of the `|` from the line before the data. So, I'm trying to figure out how I can use those character positions to correctly capture the column variables.

It seems to me like the following should work:

```
@(define os)@/[ ]*/@(end)
Item Time    Type   Width     Area      Area    Name
@(skip 1 1)
@(coll)@{field /(-)+/}@(chr sep)@(until)@(eol)@(end)
@(collect :gap 0 :vars (item time type width area area_pct name))
   @item@(os    )@(chr (toint [sep 0]))@(os)@\
   @time@(os    )@(chr (toint [sep 1]))@(os)@\
   @type@(os    )@(chr (toint [sep 2]))@(os)@\
   @width@(os   )@(chr (toint [sep 3]))@(os)@\
   @area@(os    )@(chr (toint [sep 4]))@(os)@\
   @area_pct@(os)@(chr (toint [sep 5]))@(os)@\
   @name@(os    )@(chr (toint [sep 6]))@(os)@(eol)
@(end)
Totals : @total
@(skip)
@(output)
Item,Time,Type,Width,Area,Area(%),Name
@  (repeat)
@item,@time,@type,@width,@area,@area_pct,@name
@  (end)
@(end)
```

But none of the rows of data are matching. What am I missing?

The desired output (as a CSV table) is:

```
Item,Time,Type,Width,Area,Area(%),Name
1,0.323,A B,0.0000,0.00000,0.00000,ABC
2,1.581,C,0.0000,0.00000,0.00000,DEF
3,2.898,D2,0.0000,0.0000,0.00000,GHI
```

The following code is a "hack" which produces the desired output, but does so leveraging mostly `TXR Lisp` instead of `TXR`. The closer I can make the code reflect the data file, the happier my future self will be.

```
@(define os)@/[ ]*/@(end)
Item Time    Type   Width     Area      Area    Name
@(skip 1 1)
@(coll)@{field /(-)+/}@(chr sep)@(until)@(eol)@(end)
@(collect :gap 0 :vars (item time type width area area_pct name))
@  (cases)
Totals : @(skip)
@    (accept)
@  (or)
@line
@  (set line @(progn (mapdo (lambda (s) (chr-str-set line s #\|)) (rest (reverse sep))) line))
@  (set line @(mapcar 'trim-str (split-str line "|")))
@  (bind item     @[line 0])
@  (bind time     @[line 1])
@  (bind type     @[line 2])
@  (bind width    @[line 3])
@  (bind area     @[line 4])
@  (bind area_pct @[line 5])
@  (bind name     @[line 6])
@  (end)
@(end)
@(skip)
@(output)
Item,Time,Type,Width,Area,Area(%),Name
@  (repeat)
@item,@time,@type,@width,@area,@area_pct,@name
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Comment: You should specify in which language you program (and if want replies only in that language) by adding the appropriate tag.

Comment: @wdkrnls, which programming language is it ?

Comment: also : what is the output you expect, seems you're are trying to compute something (`@total`)

Comment: Okay, created the `txr` tag and added it to the question.  http://www.nongnu.org/txr/

Comment: @Setop calling `txr -B script.txr data.txt` will print bash executable variable bindings if the query matches the data.

Comment: `(mapdo (lambda (s) (chr-str-set line s #\|)) list)` -> `(mapdo (do set [line @1] #\|) list)`.

Comment: `@(bind (item time type width ...) line)`

Comment: That last `@(bind ...)` example looks promising. Also, I think I discovered that I need to use an `@` before `toint` in the original code. I'm hoping to use as much `txr

Comment: On the surface, the issue with the nonworking code is that it relies on `@(os)` to perform ever lengthening search for the right amount of space until the following `@(chr)` matches. But `os` just wraps a regex which won't do that; regexes aren't integrated into the search algorithm and just used as regexes:  `os` just going to consume the maximum token of consecutive spaces without regard for any context.

Comment: That makes sense. Using `@*x` and `@(set x @(trim-str x))` appears to work.

Comment: Pretty silly old limitation that we can't directly specify `trim-str` as a filter for `@(output :filter ...)`. Just TXR functions.  Trimming as an output filtering operation is otherwise a possibly attractive alternative, if the data doesn't have to be trimmed for any other processing purpose.

Comment: Not even sure that it has to be `@*x`; does it not work with `@x`? There is no real choice there between longest and shortest match; it has to match to the specific column. I'm just suspecting that `@*x` might wastefully keep looking past the first `chr` match for another one farther away that won't happen (and so then falls back on the original one anyway).

Comment: I wonder if a nice function could wrap that numeric column extracting logic with trimming and all, which could then just be called like `@(get sep 0 item)@(get sep 1 time)...`

Comment: Possible way to use Lisp anyway, in context of column-based solution: `(where (op eql #\|) "xxxx|xxxxxx|xx|")` -> `(4 11 14)`.  ALSO: `(rra #/\|/ "xxxx|xxxxxx|xx|")` -> `(#R(4 5) #R(11 12) #R(14 15))` (rra: regex range all). Then `[mapcar from (rra #/\|/ "xxxx|xxxxxx|xx|")]` -> `(4 11 14)`.

Comment: Would you consider it "idiomatic" to add a `:separate-at` keyword to the `@(coll)` directive so that we could do this in two steps`@(coll :separate-at (mapcar (fun toint) sep))@line@(end)` followed by `@(bind (item time type width ...) line)`?